# Why is using .reader() skipping the first line and .readlines() isn't?

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to read in all the data from a .csv file. First, I tried using csv.reader(), but this would skip the first line of my file. I was able to remedy this using .readlines(), but I am wondering why this happens with .reader() and would like to make it read my first line.

```
import glob
import csv

new_cards = []
path = 'C:\\Users\\zrc\\Desktop\\GCData2\\*.asc'
files = glob.glob(path)


# First Method

for name in files:
    with open(name) as f:
        for line in f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            for row in reader:
                new_cards.append(row)
print(len(new_cards))


# Second Method

for name in files:
    with open(name) as f:
        m = f.readlines()
        for line in m:
            new_cards.append(line)

print(len(new_cards))
```

Comment: `*.asc` how this is a csv file ?

Comment: Have you tried [rows](https://github.com/turicas/rows) lib? Make things easier to read csv and structured data

Comment: @bhansa .asc is the format in which the program I am using writes them (it is a file with data separated by commas). I have successfully used csv.reader() on these files. It seems to be having trouble when I try to do many of them at a time.

Comment: Don't use `for line in f`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you were correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first function you dont need to use `for line in f:` this line is taking your first line and then the reader starts from the second.

The correct way should be:

```
for name in files:
    with open(name) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for row in reader:
            new_cards.append(row)
print(len(new_cards))
```

You dont need to iterate over each line in the first one because you are already doing it with `for row in reader:`